# How to reduce dimensions of Gaussian Mixture Model parameters

Tags: matlab, gaussian

Assuming I have already built a Gaussian Mixture Model using the `fitgmdist` function and want to map the multivariate distributions into a subspace with a smaller dimension without having to recreate the model how do I go about it?

In MATLAB terms, I have a GMM, `gmm_goal`, with `gmm_goal.NumComponents` = K and `gmm_goal.NumVariables` = N and want to reduce N to a number n < N.

If code isn't available, an explanation or mathematical derivation will do.

Comment: Is your subspace linear?

Comment: In this case it isn't.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the answer for a non-linear transformation. Are you interested in an answer for the linear case?

Comment: That will be helpful. I can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the Gaussian Mixture Model effected by the transformation into a subspace are the mean and variance of the Gaussian distributions that form the GMM.

Assuming a linear transformation of your data points **x**:

```
y = A*x + b
```

Because of *linearity of expectation*, we can calculate the new mean and variance of the subspace from the old ones:

```
mean_new = A*mean + b
variance_new = A*variance*A'
```